# Java 8 stream within stream parallelism

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a fairly complicated process that requires several levels of nested for loops.

Actions are only performed for one specific set of conditions. In other words:

```
for(){ 
    if(){ 
        for(){ 
            if(){
                //Something happens RIGHT HERE
            }
            //And maybe here
        }
    }
}
```

No else statements, just one solid code path iterating through a bunch of different types of objects.

My question is, if I were to replace this logic with streams (considering how many operations the CPU has to perform to complete this cycle, I think paralleling the process is the way to go) and I have a stream within a stream within a stream (BWOOOMMMPPPPPPP INCEPTION NOISE) and I parallelstream() the top level, will the streams beneath that top level still run in sequence, but just within their own respective threads?

```
    toplevelItems.parallelstream().forEachOrdered{
       //Does this stuff run in series within as many threads as there are toplevelItems
       otherObjects.stream().forEach{
           //or Naw?
           stillOtherObjects.stream().forEach{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything below the top `parallelStream()` is going to be done in a serial fashion. I assume you are working with something like a `List<List<>>`, so you will be creating a new stream below the top level which has no connection to the top one.

Comment: Correct. The method uses multiple lists passed in as arguments then iterated over by the for loops I was using. Once I figured out the potential number of iterations though, I realized parallel processing could essentially cut my iterations in half or even into fourths (using 2 to 4 cores), which I assume will save a deal of time! I'll measure of course, but I'm confident parallelism is the way to go here.